# Setting custom font to aspose words java does not work

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

Im trying to set a custom font, but it does not work. What am I missing here?

```
/src/main/resources/fonts/fonts
  -> Helvetica
  -> OpenArrow


String path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("fonts").getPath();
FontSettings.setFontsSources(
        new FontSourceBase[] {
                new FolderFontSource(path, true, 1),
                new SystemFontSource(0)
        }
);
FontSettings.setDefaultFontName("Helvetica");


Document outputDoc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(outputDoc);
builder.getFont().setName("Helvetica");
```

Helvetica font folder:
[image]

**Aspose words version**: 15.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of Aspose.Words, you should use `FontSettings.getDefaultInstance()`. Please see the following code example:

```java
FontSettings.getDefaultInstance().setFontsSources(
        new FontSourceBase[] {
            new FolderFontSource("C:\\Temp\\fonts", true, 1),
            new SystemFontSource(0)
        }
);

Document outputDoc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(outputDoc);
builder.getFont().setName("Helvetica");
builder.writeln("This is Helvetica text.");
outputDoc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.pdf");
```

Follow the link for more information.
https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/specify-truetype-fonts-location/

Also I have checked the following code with the old 15.6.0 version of Aspose.Words and the output PDF document looks correct. See the screenshot.

```java
FontSettings.setFontsSources(
        new FontSourceBase[] {
            new FolderFontSource("C:\\Temp\\fonts", true, 1),
            new SystemFontSource(0)
        }
);
FontSettings.setDefaultFontName("Helvetica");

Document outputDoc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(outputDoc);
builder.getFont().setName("Helvetica");
builder.writeln("This is Helvetica text.");
outputDoc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.pdf");
```

[image]

Comment: This is correct if you want to set fonts for specific document. I'm setting them globally.

Comment: what's more, Im using old aspose version, it differs a bit from current documentation.

Comment: Check this: https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/manipulate-and-substitute-truetype-fonts/

Comment: I have updated my answer. I checked with old 15.6.0 version and everything seems to work correct on my side.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your Helvetica font? My code which is the same as yours, still does not recognize it.

Comment: I have downloaded Helvetica font family from here https://freefontsfamily.com/helvetica-font-family/

Comment: I will accept your answer, since it sets Helvetica to example pdf (even with my code), But using Aspose words to generate complext document, it ignores Helvetica and sets Arial, must be other issue unrelated to settings font.

Comment: It was code unrelated to aspose, this works as expected.